# Mounting development docker container directory on host

Tags: docker

I am using docker for software development, as I can bundle all my dependencies (compilers, libraries, ...) within a nice contained environment, without polluting the host.

The way I usually do things (which I guess is pretty common): I have a directory on the host that only contains the source code, which is mounted into a development container using a docker volume, where my software gets built and executed. Thanks to volumes being in sync, any changes in the source is reflected within the container.

Here is the pitfall: when using a code editor, software dependencies are considered broken as they are not accessible from the host. Therefore linting, etc... does not work.

I would like to be able to mount, let's say `/usr/local/include` from the container onto the host so that, be correctly configuring my editor, I can fix all the warnings.

I guess docker volume is not the solution here, because it would override the contained file system...

Also, I'm using Windows (no choice here) therefore my flow is:

`Windows > Samba > Linux Host > Docker > Container`

and I'd prefer not switching IDE (VS Code).

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You basically wish you could reverse mount a volume from the container to the host. This is unfortunately not possible with Docker, and there are variants of this question here: [How to mount a directory in docker container to host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36246094/how-to-mount-a-directory-in-docker-container-to-host)

You're stuck with copying the files from the container to the host. As far as the host path matching `/usr/local/include` or having to use a different folder depends upon your setup.

The easiest solution which would not require changing the docker image would be to use `docker cp` to copy the files.

Otherwise, you could automate this by having the image on entry (after installing all dependencies) copy the files to `/tmp/include` and mount a host volume to that location.

Answer (score 0):

I use https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-mount-docker-volume-along-with-subfolders-on-the-host/120482/13 to expose python libraries from inside the container to a folder locally so that neovim can read the libraries for autocomplete/jump to definitions.