# How create a reverse bind volume with docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, devops

maybe it's a stupid question but, i would like to know how can i bring the data,folders and code FROM my container in MY desktop to work with my IDE with docker-compose, is it possible?

Thank you in advance to everyone!

Comment: Manually - you can always try `docker cp ` command to move data from/to container .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can access data inside your container from your local machine using docker volume.

Run your container with binding docker volume with your local file system like this:

```
docker run --name=<name> -d -v <local_directory>:<directory_inside_container> <image>
```

for instance, you have [nginx](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-share-data-between-the-docker-container-and-the-host) container and you want to access container logs on local, you can do something like this:

```
docker run --name=nginx -d -v ~/nginxlogs:/var/log/nginx -p 5000:80 nginx
```

where `~/nginxlogs` is directory on your local, while `/var/log/nginx` is the directory inside container.

Now you can access container logs in `nginxlogs` directory on local.

For `docker-compose.yml` add volume tag like this:

```
volumes:
    - ~/nginxlogs:/var/log/nginx
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply, with docker-compose is it possible?

Comment: I edited the answer to add volume tag using docer-compose.yml

Comment: Note: this technique mounts the local folder ~/nginxlogs into the container - if any files already existed in the container's /var/log/nginx folder at the time that the container starts, those files are not visible in ~/nginxlogs. Furthermore, those files are no longer available in the container either, as docker overlays the ~/nginxlogs with the container's /var/log/nginx directory.

Comment: This will NOT create a reverse bind volume like the question asks for.  This will create a normal bind volume: a blank folder on the host machine called `~/nginxlogs` and blast away any files already in `/var/log/nginx` inside the docker container.  This answer is not only misleading but dangerous as it will delete data inside the container.  The real answer is that it's not possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45788253/