# How to mount a Docker container locally (as I would a usb drive) on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, docker, mount

There are [existing resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40043887/how-to-mount-a-directory-inside-a-docker-container-on-linux-host) on how to mount local directories inside of a docker container- but what I want to do is the opposite- I'd like to mount my Docker container on my local macOS machine (as I could do when I mount a USB drive) so that I can manipulate the files inside using Sublime Text.

Is this possible on OS X? If so- how to do it?

Maybe it can be achieved somehow with [`osxfx`](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#ownership)?

The following command will mount my local `Desktop` inside of my Docker container, which is the **opposite** of what I want — what I need is something along the lines of — my Docker container shows up on my local Desktop.

```
docker run -it -v ~/Desktop:/Desktop smatthewenglish/mico-botnet:aleph bash
```

The point is - editing files with `nano` or `vim` is really *annoying* - I want to edit files with my own version of Sublime Text, which is configured just the way I like it.

As I develop a Docker container- install different applications and configure the settings, etc. I want to do that in my preferred development environment which lives on my local machine.

Comment: There is no difference: in both cases you will have a directory shared between your OS and the container. If you start a container with a shared volume (e.g. /var/data on both side), you will see everything it will write inside the container /var/data, on your OS /var/data directory. The only different case I can image is if your container contains stored data before it starts... Am I wrong?

Comment: What I want to do is edit the files on my docker container inside of Sublime Text which lives on my local machine

Comment: Do you want to edit ALL files (from root /) of your container from your host OS? Or only a specific folder?

Comment: ideally I'd like to edit all the times from root

Comment: You should take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296753/can-you-run-gui-apps-in-a-docker-container) and [this](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/8710)

Comment: [Cross-posted to Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/6yfxw9/how_to_mount_a_docker_container_locally_as_i/).

Answer (score 2):

That's not really how Docker works and not possible. You can't (not really but still) and (definitely) shouldn't edit files inside a container. You always mount a folder INTO a docker container, never FROM.

There's a few different possible scenarios:

- You want to develop something: you mount the source folder inside a docker container and can edit locally
- You want to publish something: with a Dockerfile you create a new image and copy your files inside the container

In the first case your container might provide a webserver or something like that (we work that way to host nginx + php in a container and our sources on the host). On the second case you want a self contained application to deploy on a server and all files needed should be inside the image.

Even if in some way you were able to edit files inside a running container, changes wouldn't be persisted unless you commit to a new image but that seems overly complicated and strange workflow.

Comment: the thing is- editing files with nano or vim is really annoying- I want to edit files with Sublime Text, which is configured the way I like it- you know what I mean? So as I develop a docker container- install different applications and configure the settings, etc. I want to do that in my prefered development environment which lives on my local machine- you know what I mean?

Comment: Yes and as I said you don't edit files inside the container. You expose your local files into it if needed (during development) then build a new image and copy your files for deployment.